# Executing a cURL request to an background remover API from PHP throws file not found error

Tags: api, http-headers, php-curl

I am new to cURL from PHP. I am trying to send file URL as post field and API Key as header to the background remover API to retrieve the background removed image. The error says:

> {"errors":[{"title":"No image given","code":"missing_source","detail":"Please provide the source image in the image_url, image_file or image_file_b64 parameter."}]}

My code:

```
<?php
    $url='https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg'; 
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $data = array('image_url'=> 'https://www.requestingservicebyme.com/upload/imageexample.jpg');
    $headers1=['X-API-Key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type:application/json'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
        
      if (empty($buffer)) {
         echo " buffer is empty ";
      } else{
         echo $buffer;
      }
      curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on it using the curl I got success in that ..!

Change your headers
**Remove the application type json from headers as this api returns the data in Image content format.**

```
$x = curl_init();

$headers=['X-API-Key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'];
$data = array (

'image_url' => "https://amblin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/castaway_2000_photo_29.jpg",
'size' => "auto",
);
$url = 'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg';
// $post = http_build_query($data);
$x = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$y = curl_exec($x);
curl_close($x);

//And then save it using this code    
$fp = fopen("result.jpg", "wb");
fwrite($fp, $y);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).